# Truck overheating; no coolant flow through radiator

Tags: cooling-system, overheating, gmc, sierra

I have a 95 GMC Sierra 5.7 it suddenly overheated one day and the upper radiator hose busted. So far I've changed upper and lower hoses thermostat and water pump and flushed radiator. All new parts put on yesterday Truck is still overheating and not getting water flow from radiator. I removed thermostat completely to see if water would flow through and nothing it just stays in radiator. I'm completely lost and radiator is only 7 months old

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you describe better what you mean by "overheating"? Is it the radiator boils over? Or does the dash gauge indicate it as such?

Comment: Have you checked if the water pump is running?

Comment: The dash gauge indicates and upper radiator hose gets hot but radiator doesn't boil I removed lower hoses and nothing is coming from water pump

Comment: It's belt driven pump so it should be I'm about to take it back off and put the old back on just to see if something happens  the old was just leaking from the inspection plate gasket

Comment: Any other trouble shooting  suggestions?

Comment: You completely removed the lower radiator hose and nothing came out? And, how bad did it overheat? How long did you run it after the hose busted?

Comment: I removed it from the pump to see if water was flowing through the block and nothing  comes out the pump.

Comment: I didn't I pulled  over got the ol lady to pick me up and we went got new hose and  I changed it there after I put new hose on when I was filling  the radiator back up I had a slow leak from water pump. I drove it  maybe   3.5 miles tops back to the house and changed pump and lower hose on the drive back with old pump it didn't overheat

Comment: If this is the case, you don't have enough fluid in the radiator/cooling system. You need to bleed the air out of the system. Put the vehicle up on a slant with the engine up. Then try to add more coolant. A large gush of coolant should have come out of the pump with or without it working.

Comment: So I'm hoping and guessing I just got a crap pump from the part store

Comment: OK so Jack it up slightly and add more coolent

Comment: OP curious if you ever got to the solution...any news?

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree with Paulster2 that you don't have enough coolant in the system.  One thing I've found extremely helpful in getting cooling systems properly filled up is one of these [Lisle 24610 Spill-Free Funnels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A4EAV0).  I think I first saw one in an EricTheCarGuy video:

[image]

Basically, it let's you get the coolant level higher than any other part of the cooling system, and you can run the engine with it connected to help get air out without worrying about spilling coolant all over the place. There's [a nice thread here](http://my.is/forums/f87/infamous-gurgling-behind-c-need-help-plz-415033/index3.html#post6545632) that talks more in depth about it.

Comment: Great suggestion, Robert. I need to get me one of these kits!

Answer (score 1):

More for other readers than the OP, but I found this thread by asking "[New Water Pump Overheating](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=new%20water%20pump%20overheating)".

I've got a Chevy Blazer with the 4.3 V6, and right after replacing my water pump, I filled the radiator ('til it seemed it wouldn't take anymore coolant), cap'd it, and then started her. The temp climbed quickly and I sensed something was wrong when it reached operating temp but kept rising. So I killed the engine, came inside, and found this thread.

Indeed...returned outside, removed the cap. Bone dry. So I drove up onto the curb (I currently live in an apt) to get the radiator cap at the highest point, topped it off, *started it*, and gradually added fluid until it seemed *truly* couldn't accept anymore coolant.

That did the trick. I was afraid I either installed a bad water pump (like the OP) or some other kind of worse.. This was a useful thread so I wanted to add my similar symptoms and confirm the solution for any other passers-by.